Remove AM/PM in gutenberg add/edit post and use 24-h format
How can I setup 24-hour format, and still keep the english language in wordpress. (tried us, australian, uk, south africa)
See screenshot. I tried everything, found this url, but it does not tell me how to change it: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/date-time/
Read through stackoverflow, and none seem to address this exact issue.


The date formats are hardcoded in getFullPostScheduleLabel() but you might be able to replace the format string via a translation string filter of some sort.
